# Method don't return int value from scanner in method

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, return-value

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    choiceList();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        // do something
        break;
        case 2:
        // do something
        break;
        case 0:
        break;
    }
 }
 public static int choiceList() {
     Scanner jauns = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
     System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
     System.out.println("0. Exit");
     int choice = jauns.nextInt();
     return choice;
 }
```

The thing is that the method choiceList() dont return int choice. IDE shows - java: cannot find symbol
If i declare this method in /public static void main/ method it shows - void cannot return, but it is java main method and cannot be changed. So how can i return int value from method in main method?

This is a bit confusing, tried to look up everywhere... Thats not all code, but the part that doesn't work.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The method does return the value. You just are trying to use it wrong. You need to assign the return value to a variable if you want to use it: `int choice = choiceList();`. Note that the name can of the variable can be chosen by you, so `int alibaba = choiceList();`  and then doing `switch(alibaba)` is just as valid. The name of the variable inside the method and the name of the variable you assign the return value to have no relationship to another.

Comment: I just realized that you are also trying to define your method inside the main method.... This is not valid java. You can't define methods inside other methods. Honestly I would recommend taking a step back reading a basic tutorial about how methods/ return values etc work in java.

Comment: Thanks a lot- int choice = choiceList();== worked fine. I'm new to java and still learning, reading. And sometimes there are spots where logic just don't work, and just need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're ignoring the return value of `choiceList`. You could save it to a variable in order to use it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice = choiceList();

    switch (choice) {
        // decide what to do based on the value of choice
```

Answer (score 0):

You have also a mismatch in your brackets as your `choiceList` method seems part of the `main` method. Please see my following correction of your code which also includes the other's suggestions that you should store the return value of your `choiceList` method in a new variable which you would evalute in your switch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int choice = choiceList();
  switch (choice) {
      case 1:
          // do something
          break;
      case 2:
          // do something
          break;
      case 0:
          break;
  }
} // end the main method

public static int choiceList() {
    Scanner jauns = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
    System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
    int choice = jauns.nextInt();
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that value returned by choiceList method is not assigned to variable. You can try smth like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice = choiceList();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            // do something
            break;
        case 2:
            // do something
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
    }

}

public static int choiceList() {
    Scanner jauns = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
    System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
    int choice = jauns.nextInt();
    return choice;
}
```